# How to avoid "git post-receive hook - remote: git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'"?

Tags: git, githooks

I wrote a `post-receive` hook to pull from central when somebody else is pushing.
My problem is that I see:

```
remote: git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

However, when I pull manually, everything goes ok.
There's my hook:

```
dir=${PWD##*/}
cd "/cygdrive/d/repos/.non-bare/$dir"
unset GIT_DIR
git pull
```

How would you fix that hook in order to avoid the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I would also unset `GIT_WORK_TREE` to be sure:

```
#!/bin/sh
dir=${PWD##*/}
cd "/cygdrive/d/repos/.non-bare/$dir"
unset GIT_DIR
unset GIT_WORK_TREE
git pull
```

You also can specify explicitly the right git dir and work tree in the `git pull` command itself:

```
git --work-tree=/cygdrive/d/repos/.non-bare/$dir --git-dir=/cygdrive/d/repos/.non-bare/$dir/.git pull
```

Comment: @bglow could you add an `echo /cygdrive/d/repos/.non-bare/$dir` in your hook in order to see if the path displayed is indeed the one of a repo? (one with a `.git` folder in it)

Comment: @bglow then, from that folder, do a `git remote -v`, to see if '`origin`' is defined, and reference an url/path which is the one of your bare repo.

Comment: origin is the repository i'm looking for